# Consuming web services in Lotus Notes 6.5

Tags: soa, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript

How can we consume any web services in Lotus Notes 6.5. I have seen reference to Soap Connect API. Is it the only way to do it..?

Any example will be a great help..

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

There is no out of the box solution for LotusScript and WS Consumers in R6. You would need to create your own system to shape the SOAP request, send it to the server and parse the SOAP response.

You are not going to get the benefits from using Web Services in this fashion. The whole point is that you should not have to do this.

If you use the Java route you can use Apache Axis libraries to add consuming functionality.

http://axis.apache.org/axis/

Here is a very old developerworks article on it:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-webservices/

Ultimately though I'd recommend to upgrade to a later version that does support WS consumers in LotusScript. Although be aware that LS suffers in WS due to limitations of the programming language.

Comment: I followed the instructions, BUTwhenver any constructor inititializationoccurs it is showing NoClassDEfFoundError.

Comment: i suppose i did them as instructed. I am using aml-apis.jar from xerces-2_11_0. It compiles w/o any error. see what i did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717880/noclassdeffounderror-while-using-axis-with-lotus-notes-6-5

Comment: Now I am getting this erroe.I removed and that also wont help. Now that error is gone and new error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.w3c.dom.Element: method getLocalName()Ljava/lang/String; not found

Comment: Those sort of errors normally mean a corrupted XML being parsed (Not always though). If you are pulling the XML via a URL, try opening that same thing in the browser or saving to a text file. You might be getting a login error instead of your XML code.  I would still recommend to upgrade to a version that supports consuming web services as R6 is very out of date.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in R6 is creating Web based agents using LotusScript which behaved like Web Services. It performed rather good for services that weren't called by too many users at the same time (as far as I remeber...)-

This presentation / sample might be helpful for you: 
http://www.slideshare.net/billbuchan/jmp206-lotus-domino-web-services-jumpstart#btnNext
Full files from Bill's presentation including sample are available for download here:
http://www.hadsl.com/HADSL.nsf/Documents/Lotusphere+2008+-+JMP206+-+Web+Services+Bootcamp!OpenDocument

Another helpful link (if you want to use SOAP/Java):
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/tutorials/lswsdom65/lswsdom65-pdf.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you can use a COM object in LotusScript to call the webservice.
A good one that I used myself is PocketSOAP: http://www.pocketsoap.com/ . It has a lot of features, like support for https, using SOAP headers and sending attachments.

Many of PocketSOAPs features are unavailable or difficult to achieve even in a native R8 web service consumer, so this is an option for higher versions than Lotus Notes 6.5, too.